# How to uninstall .bin installed file in ubuntu

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I have no much experience with Ubuntu I have installed .bin file but Now I'm not able to uninstall it I have tried some commands like :

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

I have searched a lot on it but could not find any fix. If you guys have any clue please share it with me, Thank You!

Comment: As it is now there is no way for any one to give you any help. What version of Ubuntu? What EXACT command did you use to install the file? What is the full file name?

Comment: Can you mention how you installed package ?

Comment: the `apt-get` commands will reverse installs that were installed by `apt-get` but cannot reverse installs that were done in other ways. Without specific details (what OS, release, what package exactly you installed) we cannot know how to reverse it - but it's the reverse of how you installed it (ie. if `apt-get install` it's `apt-get remove`; if it was `snap install` it's `snap remove` etc...

Comment: A `.bin` file, when run with `sudo`, can place files anywhere in the system. There is no obvious way of reverting that process. Perhaps if we knew what `.bin` file you ran, we could find out how to clean up your system. Or perhaps the author of the package also gave you uninstall instructions.

Comment: Do you install the software using a bash script?